# How do write the following piece of code in R?

Tags: r, sql

I am trying to write a piece of code for R to fetch data from an api with the following command:

```
data <- read.csv("https://...../api/dataservice?sql = select * from db where name IN (?)")
```

The parenthesis are where I need to input 218 different name tags. How can I do this programmatically? It is possible to write down few of them, but over 200 is not possible. Is there a way this? Can I use a character vector containing the names?

Comment: Aside: what happens if I call that API with `sql=DROP TABLE students; --`?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the names in R, you can iterate over the vector of names, and use the `paste` function. [Here's the help page for it](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html). `sprintf` would be [another option](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html), if you prefer that approach.

An example of this would be

```
names <- c("a", "b", "c")
querystring_a <- "https://...../api/dataservice?sql = select * from db where name IN "
querystring_b <- '\\'
querystring_c <- "\'"
for(n in names){
    cat(paste(querystring_a, querystring_b, querystring_c, n, querystring_c, sep=""), sep="\n")
}
```

Return:

```
https://...../api/dataservice?sql = select * from db where name IN \'a'
https://...../api/dataservice?sql = select * from db where name IN \'b'
https://...../api/dataservice?sql = select * from db where name IN \'c'
```

Comment: Do you mean for(nm in names){ data <- read.csv("https://...../api/dataservice?sql = select * from db where name IN nm ") and then append the data together ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added example code! I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: I am having difficulty: I need to input the names like this: where IN (\'name1\',\'name2\') .  How do I insert that \ (back slash) in there. I tried paste0, Everytime, i tried to use past0, it comes out as: (\\'name1\\',\\'name2\\') which is giving error. So I do need a single back slash followed by the single quote. Any help as to how to use paste to get me the single backslash ?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow...does the replacing the print line with the following fix it?   print(paste("https://...../api/dataservice?sql = select * from db where name IN \'", n, "\'", sep="")) From that, I get the following example output: "https://...../api/dataservice?sql = select * from db where name IN 'a'"

Comment: As I understand, in order to use sql command inside read.csv, in the WHERE clause, we need to enter the names as `\' name1\',\'name2\',etc` and not simply as 'name1,name2, etc' .... now when i am trying to use the paste function, it is giving me `\\'name1\\',\\'name2\\',etc`. I couldn't get rid off those extra backslashes. I need single backslash not double.

Comment: Ah! I understand now. I think the updated code will address your issue! I also updated it to hopefully be easier to follow, by assigning the strings to variables before getting to the tricky bit.